# MySQL collation server variables user dependent?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

Connecting with different SQL users with the same client (Sequel Pro) on the same MySQL server on the same database results in different collation server variables.

In my.cnf, I included the following:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci, NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Connecting with user A results in:

```
collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci
collation_database = utf8_unicode_ci
collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
init_connect = SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci, NAMES utf8
```

Connecting with user B results in:

```
collation_database = utf8_unicode_ci
collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
init_connect = SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci, NAMES utf8
```

So the collation_connection variable is missing. Is it possible the init_connect is ignored / user specific for some reason?

Because the collation_connection is not set, a `Illegal mix of collations` error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible cause: The `init_connect` string seems to be wrong. Try:

`init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci; SET NAMES utf8;'`

and then restart the mysql service.

This does not explain the weird behaviour with the SUPER permission however..

Comment: The solution was a mix between this answer and @Oldskool. Removing the init_connect string resulted in the desired collation_connection. Reason that it was already working for user A, was the SUPER permission not executing the init_connect.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that `init_connect` is not run when a user with `SUPER` privileges logs in. This is a security feature, [as documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect):

> The content of init_connect is not executed for users that have the SUPER privilege. This is done so that an erroneous value for init_connect does not prevent all clients from connecting.

This is to prevent from locking yourself out of the database completely:

> For example, the value might contain a statement that has a syntax error, thus causing client connections to fail. Not executing init_connect for users that have the SUPER privilege enables them to open a connection and fix the init_connect value.

So it is expected behavior for these users not to have this variable set upon connecting.

Comment: that makes sense. The weird thing is, user A has SUPER privilege. User B not. Giving user B the same permissions as user A solves the problem. Do you have an explanation for that?